# Wanting to get a Minecraft server status on my website

Tags: html, web, server, minecraft

I am currently making a website which will show if a certain Minecraft server is online but I can't find any code on how to do this. I'd like some help with this as I am a beginner at both HTML and Javascript and can't figure it out, even when googling.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

Took some code from some other people, but this works well. Just change the server where I commented insert server here in the JS code and then change the name of server in the html if you want to change it to another server. If nobody is online or server is down it says server offline.

This example is for hypixel:

```js
//based on a pen by @robinselmer
var url = "https://api.minetools.eu/ping/hypixel.net"; //insert  server here

$.getJSON(url, function(r) {
  //data is the JSON string
  if (r.error) {
    $('#rest').html('Server Offline');
    return false;
  }
  var pl = '';
  if (r.players.sample.length > 0) {
    pl = '<br>OP: ' + r.players.sample[0].name;
  }
  $('#rest').html(r.description.replace(/§(.+?)/gi, '') + '<br><b>Players Online:</b> ' + r.players.online + pl);
  $('#favicon').attr('src', r.favicon);

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/iCZSjWa.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -2px
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 3px #0002;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: 0
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: crosshair;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.header h2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  right: 10px;
  top: 135px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 3px #0002;
  z-index: 9
}

#rest {
  padding: 30px 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #000d42
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="card">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/808180587605331969/u-CULTwl_400x400.jpg" id="favicon"></div>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="image"> <img src="http://hypixel.net/proxy.php?image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FjkFk4TU.png&hash=ec5b70a2ba4c4f79b5031ac356695a13" alt="" /> </div>

    <h2>hypixel.net</h2>
    <!-- put server name here !-->
  </div>
  <div id="rest">Loading ...</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that does not want to use an external API, and uses backend as well, this is the solution.

1. Install these two packages:

[MinecraftStatusPinger](https://github.com/woodendoors7/MinecraftStatusPinger) from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraftstatuspinger) by doing `npm install minecraftstatuspinger`, which is used for pinging the minecraft server.. This is faster than if you were contacting an API which pings the server for you on their behalf.

[Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) by doing `npm install express`, which is used for making the back-end which will send the site to the user.

2. Import them both, and start a new Express server

```js
import mc from "minecraftstatuspinger"
import express from "express"
var app = express();
 
var server = app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Running on http://localhost:5000');
});
```

3. Listen for anyone opening up the website, and when they do, ping the minecraft server.

```js
app.get('/', async (req: any, res: any) => {
    let serverIP = "mc.hypixel.net";
    let ping = await mc.lookup({ host: serverIP });
    let html = `
        <h1>Pinging server ${serverIP}</h1>
        <p>Latency: ${ping.latency}ms</p>
        <p>MOTD: ${ping?.status?.description}ms</p>
        <p>Players: ${ping?.status?.players.online}/${ping?.status?.players.max}</p>
    `
    res.send(html + css);
})
```

This will give the user the server's IP, ping, MOTD or server description and number of players on the server.
Combine the HTML and the CSS, and send it to the user along with the information.

4. Declare the simplistic CSS. You can skip this step if you don't need CSS for now.

```js
let css = `
    <style>
        body, html {
            background-color: #1c1b22;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>`
```

You're done. Any user that now visits the website will get the minecraft server's status.